# The CSS modules in React.js do not load

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am learning React.js and I am using a Udemy course. The thing is that since the course was made and now, React was updated and CSS modules were changed. I tried to make my research and wrote the code, but the classes seem to not apply. I checked with inspect in the browser and under the React tab(with the extension installed) it says className={undefined}. Under the inspector tab it says just

```
<div>...</div>
```

without any class applied. 
I named the css files as [component].module.css

This is one component, I did all the same and all have this problem:

```
import React from 'react';
// import Aux from '../../hoc/Aux';
import Ingredient from './Ingreditent/Ingredient';
import styles from './Burger.module.css';

const burger = props => (
    <div className={styles.Burger}>
        <Ingredient type='bread-top' />
        <Ingredient type='meat'/>
        <Ingredient type='bread-bottom' />
    </div>
);

export default burger;
```

And here is the CSS file, Burger.module.css:

```
.Burger{
    width: 50vw;
    height: 30vh;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: scroll;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) and (min-height: 700px){
    .Burger{
        width: 70vw;
        height: 30vw;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Lines 143 to 150 of webpack.config.dev.js:
The file is here https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuFJzTL8l8Op9g5CBJ8kv8Wv-pcx

```
    test: /\.css$/,
    options: {
      importLoaders: 1,
      modules: true,
       localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
    },
    loader: 'style!css?importLoaders=1!postcss'
  },
```

Comment: Did you update your `webpack.config.js` to make css module works?

Comment: I have two of these files, one prod and one dev. They change very often. I once had it with test: cssRegex now it is test: /\.css$/. I tried to but I did not manage to. I have React 16.8.6. They seem to change with every little update.

Comment: You need to submit your dev webpack config. Especially the part that says resolve: 'css$' or something like that.

Comment: I read that you could use the .module extension with a non-ejected react project too. I created a new project and it did not work.

Comment: "non-ejected react project"? Are you using Create React App?

Comment: yes I am using create-react-app. I tried too see if it works in non ejected app too. In the udemy course says that this .module.css works without ejecting by this version as specified here https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet

Comment: I managed to make it work with a non-ejected app. I went into package.json and updated the version for react scripts to 2.0.0 and ran npm install. In the new version I think you are supposed to run without the modules extensions if you go in the webpack file to manually enable modules.

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of react it should be something like this:

```
test: cssRegex,
              exclude: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                modules: true,
                modules: {
                  localIdentName: "[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]",
                },
                importLoaders: 1,
```

Old version:

```
test: /\.css$/,
    optio`enter code here`ns: {
      importLoaders: 1,
      modules: true,
       localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
    },
```